# Template issues getting ajax search results

Tags: search, templates, ajax

I'm trying to put search results into a div with ajax. The issue is I'm getting errors saying `undefined function have_posts()` when the the search template is accessed. It also took issue with `get_header()` which was in the search-results.php but I took it out. Here's how I have it setup.

```
  <div id="my_search">
   <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://myurl.com/" >
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
   </form>
  </div>
  <div id="results"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchsubmit").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var search_val=$("#s").val(); 
     $.post('http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/beta/search-results.php',{search_string:search_val},function(data){
        if(data.length>0){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
     });
    });   
   });
  </script>
```

And here is the `search-results.php` template. I'm wondering if maybe I'm not passing the search results to the template.

```
<ul>
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>
  <li><a title="Permalink to this post" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
 <?php if (!have_posts()) { echo('<li>No results to show.</li>'); } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you load a template file directly that way, you're not loading the WordPress environment, so no WordPress functions are available.

Your two options are to either load the search page on the *front end* and filter the result, like:

```
$('#results').load('http://mysite.com/?s=searchterm ul#target');
```

Or build a search function using WordPress provided AJAX functionality, see [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

**EDIT**

Here's an example of how I load additional posts via AJAX which you could adapt to create a search function if you wish.

First, in `functions.php`, I enqueue my javascript and localize the script to pass the AJAX URL that will process my requests. WordPress AJAX uses `admin-ajax.php` to process all AJAX requests, front or back end:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa56343_scripts', 100 );

function wpa56343_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpa56343_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        null,
        false
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpa56343_script',
        'WPaAjax',
        array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
}
```

In `scripts.js`, my javascript that calls my AJAX action, and passes a `postoffset` var so I can pass that to the query. Note also the use of `WPaAjax.ajaxurl` to pass the URL that will process this request:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#blog-more').click(function(e){ // <- added
        e.preventDefault(); // <- added to prevent normal form submission
        var postoffset = $('.post').length;
        $.post(
            WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'wpa56343_more',
                postoffset : postoffset
            },
            function( response ) {
                $('#container').append( response );
            }
        );
    });

});
```

In `functions.php`, the function that processes my AJAX request mapped to the action I passed in the javascript above. A stripped down version of WordPress is bootstrapped, so I can access most WordPress functions:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wpa56343_more', 'wpa56343_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa56343_more', 'wpa56343_more');

function wpa56343_more(){
    global $wp_query;

    $offset = $_POST['postoffset'];
    $args = array(
        'offset' => $offset,
        'posts_per_page' => 10
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    get_template_part( 'post-template' );

    exit;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to adapt this and for some reason when I click search it takes me to another site(myurl.com?s=term). Here is the pastebin of my adaption. What am I doing wrong here? http://pastebin.com/5CqMhhDD

Comment: oh yeah, you had it right in your original code, you need to prevent the default form submission when the search is initiated, see edit above.