# Can't load search results with ajax

Tags: ajax, search, get-template-part

I'm trying to load search results on my page without reloading. I tried multiple approaches already, but I still can't make it work, despite using someone else's confirmed solution.

Please find the code below:

- search-post-results.php (in includes folder)

  ```
  <?php
  /* Template Name: Search Post Results */        
  ?>             
  <div class="contentarea">
      <div id="content" class="content_right">  
               <h3>Search Result for : <?php echo "$s"; ?> </h3>       
                   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
                       <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="posts">        
                           <article>        
                               <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><h4>          
                           </article> 
                       </div>
                   <?php endwhile; ?>
                   <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- functions.php

  ```
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa56343_search', 'wpa56343_search',100);
  add_action('wp_ajax_wpa56343_search', 'wpa56343_search',100);
  function wpa56343_search()
    {
      global $wp_query;
      $search = $_POST['search_val'];
      $args = array(
        's' => $search,
        'posts_per_page' => 5
      );
      $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
      get_template_part('includes/search-post-results');
      exit;
    }
  ```
- HTML form

  ```
  <div id="my_search">
      <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform"  >
          <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
          <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
      </form>
  </div>
  ```
- jQuery

  ```
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#searchsubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var search_val = jQuery("#s").val();
        jQuery.post(
            "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", {
              action:'wpa56343_search',
              search_string:search_val
            }, function (response) {
              jQuery('body').append(response);
            }
        }
     });
  });
  </script>
  ```

Instead of getting results on the same page, using my template, I just go to url/s?=search_val and a default search results template is loaded.

Thanks for help.

E: Slowly moving forward. After using the above code the error I'm getting is Uncaught ReferenceError: wpa56343_search is not defined.

Comment: Probably because `WPaAjax` is not defined - can you link to the original solution?

Comment: Yeah. I was trying this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56343/template-issues-getting-ajax-search-results/56349#56349 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166981/how-to-use-jquery-to-retrieve-ajax-search-results-for-wordpress . Initially I didn't even use WPaAjax, but the result was still the same.

Comment: So I'm guessing you've just got the JavaScript inline in a template, as opposed to putting it in a file and enqueuing it?

Comment: Yessssss. Should I enqueue it instead? Oh, I see it now. you mean using the wp_localize_script bit. I see it now, my bad... I 'm just editing my main question with my previous code that didn't work either.

Comment: No need - since we can run PHP in this context, just replace `WPaAjax.ajaxurl` with `"<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>"` - don't forget the quotes!

Comment: After updating with your suggestion it's still taking me to a new page instead of using my template part and printing it in body :(

Comment: Your JS event handler is failing. Use the console in your browser to see if you get any runtime errors.

Comment: I indeed had an error - wrong syntax for $.post. Managed to fix it - kind of. Now it won't go further, saying that wpa56343_search is not defined. I do have it in my functions.php though.

Comment: See my answer for an update.

Comment: To flush the permalinks or rewrite rules from your theme or plugin you need to use the flush_rewrite_rules() function. <?php flush_rewrite_rules(); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript should be:

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function ( $ ) {
        $( "#searchform" ).on( "submit", function ( ev ) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            $.post(
                "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>",
                {
                    action: "wpa56343_search",
                    search: $( "#s" ).val()
                },
                function ( response ) {
                    $( "body" ).append( response );
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the AJAX handler code in your `functions.php` should be:

```
function wpa56343_search() {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['search'] ) )
        exit;

    query_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'post_type' => get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ) ),
            's' => wp_unslash( ( string ) $_POST['search'] ),
        )
    );

    get_template_part( 'includes/search-post-results' );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa56343_search', 'wpa56343_search', 100 );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpa56343_search',        'wpa56343_search', 100 );
```

Typically you should avoid `query_posts`, but it's perfectly valid in this context as we're setting up an isolated global query for `search-post-results.php` to use.

Comment: Yes! Works like a charm. Many thanks! Out of curiosity - the error I mentioned above... Do you have any idea why I couldn't use the wpa56343_search action in my code?

Comment: It was a JS error, not to do with your AJAX handler - maybe you were missing quotes or had UTF-8 alternative quotes around `wpa56343_search` in your code.