# How to paginate Ajax result

Tags: ajax, pagination

In wordpress website i get 200 plus post with Ajax post filter.

This is the Ajax post filter code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="filter-output"> Ajax Output   </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
 // The query (compiled)
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type'       => 'tablet',
  'meta_query'  => $meta_query
));

// The Loop
if( $query->have_posts() ) :
 while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
    get_template_part('content');
endwhile;
   wp_reset_query();
else :
   _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.');
   wp_send_json($query->posts);
endif;
   the_posts_pagination() ;
die();
```

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#test .br').click(function(){
  var choices = {};
  console.log(choices);

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
    type :'POST',
    data : {
      'action' : 'call_post',
      'choices' : choices,
  },

success: function (result) {
    $('.filter-output').append(result);
  }     
 });
})
});
```

What is Solution for 200 plus post which get by Ajax? `Pagination` , `Load more post button` or `else`.

I post question here after waste a lot of time on work and Google search. But i have no solution.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56349/4771). You have to pass a page number or offset with your ajax call, and use that to query for a specific page of results.

Comment: Thanks great tutorial. I have problem because something different here. In my situation i need offset for Ajax filter result not simple search result. So can you help me in question PHP part. How & what will be HTML part for `loadmore` button in my php

Comment: @Milo Here is the [Link](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/farooq/tablet/) where i testing this

Comment: Same answer. You need to pass query arguments the same way you pass page number.

Comment: @Milo can you please post answer here with changing `pass query arguments`. i am new with wordpress and also try many times but fail to achive it.